# ClamAV : freshclam hangs and uses 100% CPU

Tags: 16.04, updates, malware, antivirus, clamav

I try to update the ClamAV database by running `freshclam`. The `daily-*.cdiff` is downloaded successfully, but then the process hangs.
The CPU is maxed out at 100%, but the update just will not finish. I canceled the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after appr. 10 minutes. Here is the output from my update attempt:

```
# freshclam
ClamAV update process started at Tue Nov  8 00:15:57 2016
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
Downloading daily-22474.cdiff [100%]
```

Did anyone else observe this behavior? Is it a bug or is my system not properly configured?

PS: I am using `ClamAV v0.99.2` on Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a large Cdiff published for older users recently.  Try deleting the daily and daily cdiffs* and re-running Freshclam.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: ...and how does one delete "the daily and daily cdiffs*"...???

Comment: @woohoo I was wondering that myself - see darkdragon's answer below.

Answer (score 14):

When there is a huge `daily.cdiff` file, the update process might take a long time to finish.

Sometimes, it is faster to delete the old daily definitions and re-downloading them.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld
sudo freshclam
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Linux Mint 19.3 with ClamAV 0.100.2

Comment: Removing the `daily.cld` file didn't work for me, but removing the `main.cld` did.  It's a waste to have it re-download the whole thing, but it ensures that there are no diffs to run.

Answer (score 0):

This must have been a problem on the servers of the ClamAV mirrors. I experienced the same on two Ubuntu 16.10 workstations, on one Ubuntu 16.10 server, on one fedora 24 workstation and on two RHEL 7.3 servers yesterday simultaneously. All six operating systems showed exactly the same behavior as you describe. In the end freshclam finished successfully, it just took a very long time. Today the problem is solved, everything is working properly again on all machines. It was a one time issue, nothing you should worry about. It had nothing to do with your local installation.